# How to run Skype on Raspberry Pi

Tags: software-installation

Skype is compiled for Linux but not for arm cpu that Raspberry Pi uses, so how can I run Skype on Raspberry Pi?

Comment: Maybe running Skype on top of Android would work!

Comment: https://github.com/elmiba/Teams/wiki/Installation-guide
This guide works with raspian 32bit in chromium-browser

Answer (score 15):

There is a great video demonstration how to get Skype running on Raspberry Pi:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nqH54GyRdys

And detailed instructions are provided here:
http://elinux.org/RPi_Using_Skypekit

Comment: We should try to get detailed instructions up here.

Comment: Should probably qualify the answer to mention that you can get Skype voice calls to work through the SDK, however not yet the Skype client or video.

Comment: ya but you have to pay i dont have the money to pay

Comment: And Skype SDK is no longer available it seems

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://eltechs.com/run-skype-on-raspberry-pi/) is direct instruction how to run Skype on raspberry pi.

Comment: It should be noted that this is outdated for two reasons: (1) Skype ceased supporting 32-bit systems and (2) Eltechs ceased selling Exagear Desktop.

Answer (score 1):

If you need Skype as a chat client only, a much easier way to do is it is through a Pidgin plugin that's using Skype Web internally. You can download the plugin compiled for the RPi from http://www.zhekov.org/articles/2/skype-chat-on-raspberry-pi

Answer (score 0):

At the moment (this date) the only option is to install Android then use the Skype APK.
Not all webcam work, but basic Skype function are available.